# Is 'export default' better than 'export' in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

`export default ComponentName` 
And
`export ComponentName` .
Is it better to use the default for readability or is the export a recommended choice? Found few tutorials pertaining to react but did not find anyone who differentiated the two.

Comment: It's a matter of personal preference. Some style guides/lint rules have e.g. `prefer-default-export` if there's only one export per file.

Comment: Yes, I got a hang of it. I really thought there should have only one export per file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's anything better or worse. Only, export can export multiple modules and export default can export only one module. Therefore, I use export default for page-drawing components and export for js files that have multiple functions defined. I think you can judge and use it according to each situation.

Comment: Thanks man! This helped me understand these better.